# Mysql columns mutual exclusion

Tags: mysql, insert, check-constraints

I want to create a table which has 2 columns that would only allow one of them to have value in the same row.

I tried with CHECK constraint but it not working correctly

Ex: [SQL Fiddle schema example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66d8d0/1/0)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html
Use trigger instead.

Comment: I can't add triggers or procedures in mysql server :( , I'll check this constraint in the application side.